# How To locate current firewall rules

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I currently have port 22 open on a device running Ubuntu 22.04. When using nmap port 22 is open. using iptables -L shows that there are no rules for port 22. I then used UFW which is inactive. I have also tried iptables-legacy and iptables-nft. none of which show a rule for port 22.

What is a method that I can use to locate the current rules?

I tried to list all the firewall rules to show the rules for port 22.
adding rules to iptables does not allow access to the opened ports.
scanned with nmap.

[iptanles -L result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70PeC.png)

[Nmap portscan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19SZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely when you install OpenSSH it will open port 22 for connection, if you want to see what service and what ports that running now you can use `netstat -tulpn` with installing net-tools first `apt install net-tools`

For the Firewall rules, if you dont add the rule it will not shown on your iptables.

I Hope this Helps.